# PHP code failing query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a php code that processes the lookup of three variables, $email, $password, and $address. The user will input their current email, password, and a NEW address they want to update in the system. 
[this is the html form][1]
    The query is executing this part of the if statement:
    `enter code here`$body .= "Invalid email: $inputemail";

How come it is saying invalid email though I entered the correct info? I am new to coding so I  am having trouble figuring out what the problem is. Also, I debugged using `var_dump($db->errorInfo());` and it returned array (size=3)

```
 0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => null
  2 => null

    <?php
include_once('support.php');
include_once('connect_database.php');
//connect_database.php contains your connection/creation of a PDO to connect to your MYSQL db on bmgt406.rhsmith.umd.edu/phpmyadmin
ini_set("display_errors","1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// Initialize $title and $body.
$title = "Simple Update Request";
$body = "<fieldset><legend>" .$title . "</legend>";

// Initialize variables with values for the name of the table ($name_of_table)
// and the 3 fields - email, password, and address using method GET.
$name_of_table = "requests";

$inputemail = $_GET['email'];
$inputpassword = $_GET['password'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
var_dump($db->errorInfo());

// Check if the table exists in the db
if (tableExists($db, $name_of_table)) 
{ 
    // Prepare a SQL select query and bind the 3 variables to email, password, and address fields in your database. 

    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM $name_of_table WHERE email = :email";
    $statement1 = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);

    $statement1->bindValue(':email', $inputemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // Execute the SQL query and store in $result
    $result =  $statement1->execute();

    if (!$result) {
        // Retrieving records failed.
        $body .= "Retrieving records from table " . $name_of_table . " failed. <br/>";
    } else {
        // Retrieving records successful.
        // Retrieve result into $singleRow using fetch();
        $singleRow = $statement1->fetch();

        if (!$singleRow){
            // Invalid email address has been entered.
            $body .= "Invalid email: $inputemail";
        } else {
            if ($singleRow['password'] != $inputpassword) {
                    // If the password is not the same as $inputpassword, then an "Invalid Password" has been entered.
                $body .= "Invalid password.";
                    // Get current value from table before UPDATING the user's new address.
                } else {
                    $address = $singleRow['address'];

                    // Close previous SQl query connection before starting a new query. 
                    $statement1->closeCursor();

                    // Prepare a SQL Query to update the user information and execute the query.
                    $sqlQuery = "UPDATE " . $name_of_table . " SET email= :email, password= :password WHERE address= :address";
                    $statement1 = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $statement1->bindValue(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement1->bindValue(':email', $inputemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement1->bindValue(':password', $inputpassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // Execute the SQL query and store in $result
    $result =  $statement1->execute();
                    // If everything is correct, display the UPDATED user information found (firstname, lastname, address, email, plan)


        }
    }

    $statement1->closeCursor(); 

}
}

$body .= "<a href=\"index.html\"><input type=\"submit\" value = \"Main Menu\"/></a>";
$body .= "</fieldset>";

echo generatePage($title,$body);

?>
```

Comment: Your query only refers to one variable `:email` but you're binding `:address`, `:email`, and `:password`.

Comment: `WHERE email = :email` You don't have password or address in there.

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: The error statement is gone, but now the query is failing and is executing this code from the if statement:  if (!$result) {
        // Retrieving records failed.
        $body .= "Retrieving records from table " . $name_of_table . " failed.     <br/>";

Comment: Update the question with the new code.

Comment: `</php` is that just a bad paste? That slash should be a ?.

Comment: the sql query in the updated portion is also wrong - you would not `SET` a value in a `SELECT` statement ~ `SELECT * FROM $name_of_table set asdress = :address WHERE email = :email, password = :password` Also, why are you using GETrather than POST if this is from a form submission?

Answer (score 1):

your prepared select statement only references :email, but your trying to bind all 3 values :email, :address, and :password.

Are you failing on the first or second ->execute() statement?   My thinking is you're failing on the first execute() statement.

Comment: I fixed the statement to reference email and password and I removed the bind statement to address. I then bind email and address because the lookup is just verifying that email and password match the values stored in the db

Comment: you're now adding 'set asdress = :address' but you still have a SELECT statement.   Has your Error message changed after you updated your code?   It looks to me like you're trying to retrive a record that match's a user provided email address.  In this case, you only need to lookup a record that matches an email address.   So your Query statement should be what it was, you simply need to remove the two bindValue() statements for :address and :password.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind the "address" or "password" in your SELECT query. The reason you are getting an invalid parameter exception is because you have not bound these parameters to anything in your query (probably because you don't need to). The following should resolve your issue:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM $name_of_table WHERE email = :email";
$statement1 = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement1->bindValue(':email', $inputemail, PDO::PARAM_STR);

// Execute the SQL query and store in $result
$result =  $statement1->execute();
```

Per your comment about "the query is failing and is executing this code from the if statement" try debugging your code by adding a `var_dump($db->errorInfo());` to get a more accurate idea on what is failing.

Comment: But how come I don't need to reference password or address in my select query? I tried your code and it didn't work. It returned totally blank

Comment: Because in your select query you have not used either `:address` or `:password`. Why do you want to bind  these in your select query anyway? If the desired affect is to update this information then you will only need to bind address and password in your insert query.

Comment: Note that the `*` in your select query will fetch everything from the table `$name_of_table`

Comment: I have also made the assumption here that email is a primary key in your database.

Comment: I am looking to only update the address. But the user will input their current email and password AS verification of their identity and ALSO will enter the address they want to change their current address to.

Comment: Check @ramraider comment this is the likely reason for why your query has failed on execute.

Comment: Your update query is also wrong give that you wish to update address. In  its current form you are only updating email and password you will likley want something like this: `UPDATE " . $name_of_table . " SET address= :address WHERE email= :email`